# D3 version 4: Brush not visible / accessible, but is active in the background

Tags: javascript, d3.js

With D3 version 4 the brush concept appears to be significantly revised.  To update some other code, I'm trying to write a very simple example of brushing to be sure I understand the new paradigm.  My current code is below.  The brush is created and associated with the proper element, but is not visible or active to the user.  However, the `brush.move` call does result in a report to the console, as expected.  I want the brush action to be applied to the upper data panel, and the new paradigm makes it clear that the brush extent is pulled from the containing element (1st [paragraph here](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#brushes-d3-brush)).  Eventually the brushed region will be shown in the bottom panel.  What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
<script src = "http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"> </script>
</body>

<script>

// Using version 4 of d3!!!
// Demonstrate the simplest possible brush in version 4

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = width/2 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    offset = 20; // offset between original and brushed data

var xdata = d3.range(0, 20);
var ydata = [1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 14, 15, 15, 11, 10, 5, 5, 4, 8, 7, 5, 5, 5, 8, 10];

var xy = []; // start empty, add each element one at a time
for(var i = 0; i < xdata.length; i++ ) {
     xy.push({x: xdata[i], y: ydata[i]});
}

var xscl = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(xy, function(d) {return d.x;})) //use just the x part
    .range([margin.left, width + margin.left])

var yscl = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(xy, function(d) {return d.y;})) // use just the y part
    .range([height + margin.top, margin.top])

var myline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xscl(d.x);}) // apply the x scale to the x data
    .y(function(d) { return yscl(d.y);}) // apply the y scale to the y data

var brush = d3.brush()
    // .extent([[margin.left, margin.top],[margin.right, margin.bottom]])
    .on("end", brushed);

function brushed() {
    if (!d3.event.selection) return; // ignore empty selections
    var s = d3.event.selection,
        x0 = s[0][0],
        y0 = s[0][1],
        x1 = s[1][0],
        y1 = s[1][1];
    console.log("brush coords:", s)
}

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",window.innerWidth)
    .attr("height",window.innerHeight)

var data1 = svg.append("rect") // outline original data region
  .attr("id", "orig_data")
    .attr("x", margin.left)
  .attr("y", margin.top)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", 0.5);

var data2 = svg.append("rect") // outline brushed data region
    .attr("x", margin.left)
    .attr("y", margin.top + offset + height)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", 0.5);

svg.append("path") // draw original data
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", myline(xy)) // use the value of myline(xy) as the data, 'd'
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .style("stroke-width", 2);

var brush_region = d3.select("#orig_data")
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, [[100, 100,],[200, 200,]]);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the brush to a `rect`, this is "eating" your brush events and masking it's appearance.  Just change that element to a `g` as seen in some of the [examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6232537).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
<script src = "http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"> </script>
</body>

<script>

// Using version 4 of d3!!!
// Demonstrate the simplest possible brush in version 4

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = width/2 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    offset = 20; // offset between original and brushed data

var xdata = d3.range(0, 20);
var ydata = [1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 14, 15, 15, 11, 10, 5, 5, 4, 8, 7, 5, 5, 5, 8, 10];

var xy = []; // start empty, add each element one at a time
for(var i = 0; i < xdata.length; i++ ) {
     xy.push({x: xdata[i], y: ydata[i]});
}

var xscl = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(xy, function(d) {return d.x;})) //use just the x part
    .range([margin.left, width + margin.left])

var yscl = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(xy, function(d) {return d.y;})) // use just the y part
    .range([height + margin.top, margin.top])

var myline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xscl(d.x);}) // apply the x scale to the x data
    .y(function(d) { return yscl(d.y);}) // apply the y scale to the y data

var brush = d3.brush()
    // .extent([[margin.left, margin.top],[margin.right, margin.bottom]])
    .on("end", brushed);

function brushed() {
    if (!d3.event.selection) return; // ignore empty selections
    var s = d3.event.selection,
        x0 = s[0][0],
        y0 = s[0][1],
        x1 = s[1][0],
        y1 = s[1][1];
    console.log("brush coords:", s)
}

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",window.innerWidth)
    .attr("height",window.innerHeight)

var data1 = svg.append("g") // outline original data region
  .attr("id", "orig_data")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", 0.5);

var data2 = svg.append("rect") // outline brushed data region
    .attr("x", margin.left)
    .attr("y", margin.top + offset + height)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", 0.5);

svg.append("path") // draw original data
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", myline(xy)) // use the value of myline(xy) as the data, 'd'
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .style("stroke-width", 2);

var brush_region = d3.select("#orig_data")
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, [[100, 100,],[200, 200,]]);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark.  However, the brush as you have it can go anywhere since it is "attached" to the main svg container.  I'd like to restrict it to the `data1` region only (i.e. in the upper panel).  And I'd like to keep that outlining rectangle (can that be added in a later step?).